# @Query keep pulling null from database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, xampp

I am currently having what I'd like to call as Code Block (Writer block but with coding). I have tried to check many times and make sure that everything is in the proper place but it keeps getting me a null despite the data that I ask in the @Query is exist.

This is the @Query that I currently have,

```
@Query(value = "select d.denda from data_transaksi_model d WHERE d.tanggal=:x AND d.nama_wp = :y AND d.masa_pajak=:z", nativeQuery = true)
    String findAllDenda(String x,String y,String z);
```

My expected output from there is a collection of "denda" from the table of "data_transaksi_model" which has the specific "tanggal", "name", and "masa_pajak" from that table. I have double checked the table that is created within the database and it has the same name as to what I inquire there,

[image]

As you can see, the table name is matchup and the name of the column name that has the name of what I want in my query is also match up. Just to make sure, I also check the structure of the database and it is indeed a string, also the same with others.

[image]

The table is the byproduct of the model from my Spring Boot's project that I have made.

```
@Entity
public class DataTransaksiModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "tanggal")
    private String tanggal;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "no_kohir")
    private String noKohir;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "no_urut")
    private String noUrut;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nama_wp")
    private String namaWP;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "jam")
    private String jam;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nop")
    private String nop;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "denda")
    private String denda;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "jumlah_setoran")
    private String jumlahSetoran;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "luas_tanah")
    private String luasTanah;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "luas_bangunan")
    private String luasBangunan;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "kecamatan")
    private String kecamatan;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "kelurahan")
    private String kelurahan;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "masa_pajak")
    private String masaPajak;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "lokasi")
    private String lokasi;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "pokok")
    private String pokok;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "cabang")
    private String cabang;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "User")
    private String user;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTanggal() {
        return tanggal;
    }

    public void setTanggal(String tanggal) {
        this.tanggal = tanggal;
    }

    public String getNoKohir() {
        return noKohir;
    }

    public void setNoKohir(String noKohir) {
        this.noKohir = noKohir;
    }

    public String getNoUrut() {
        return noUrut;
    }

    public void setNoUrut(String noUrut) {
        this.noUrut = noUrut;
    }

    public String getNamaWP() {
        return namaWP;
    }

    public void setNamaWP(String namaWP) {
        this.namaWP = namaWP;
    }

    public String getJam() {
        return jam;
    }

    public void setJam(String jam) {
        this.jam = jam;
    }

    public String getNop() {
        return nop;
    }

    public void setNop(String nop) {
        this.nop = nop;
    }

    public String getDenda() {
        return denda;
    }

    public void setDenda(String denda) {
        this.denda = denda;
    }

    public String getJumlahSetoran() {
        return jumlahSetoran;
    }

    public void setJumlahSetoran(String jumlahSetoran) {
        this.jumlahSetoran = jumlahSetoran;
    }

    public String getLuasTanah() {
        return luasTanah;
    }

    public void setLuasTanah(String luasTanah) {
        this.luasTanah = luasTanah;
    }

    public String getLuasBangunan() {
        return luasBangunan;
    }

    public void setLuasBangunan(String luasBangunan) {
        this.luasBangunan = luasBangunan;
    }

    public String getKecamatan() {
        return kecamatan;
    }

    public void setKecamatan(String kecamatan) {
        this.kecamatan = kecamatan;
    }

    public String getKelurahan() {
        return kelurahan;
    }

    public void setKelurahan(String kelurahan) {
        this.kelurahan = kelurahan;
    }

    public String getMasaPajak() {
        return masaPajak;
    }

    public void setMasaPajak(String masaPajak) {
        this.masaPajak = masaPajak;
    }

    public String getLokasi() {
        return lokasi;
    }

    public void setLokasi(String lokasi) {
        this.lokasi = lokasi;
    }

    public String getPokok() {
        return pokok;
    }

    public void setPokok(String pokok) {
        this.pokok = pokok;
    }

    public String getCabang() {
        return cabang;
    }

    public void setCabang(String cabang) {
        this.cabang = cabang;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

With that finished, I insert a data dummy into the database as the following.

[image]

Therefore, I tried to put the input of `tanggal` with "1170130", `nama_wp` with "SURATNO" and `masa_pajak` with "2016". However, I keep getting null instead of "9.166" in the collection. Where did I do wrong? I am using XAMPP, MySQL, and Spring Boot for this project.

**/EDIT:** I tried it manually in my XAMPP with `SELECT denda FROM` data_transaksi_model`WHERE nama_wp="SURATNO" AND masa_pajak="2014" AND tanggal="1170130"` and it actually gives me a return

[image]

However, when I do it in my spring boot project it still return null.

**//Edit2:** I am using IntelliJ as my IDE and there is a warning (not an error) within the @Query annotation. It is said that "No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance. Disable this inspection via problem menu (alt+enter)" there is also a warning that said, "SQL dialect is not configured". If that is the source of the problem, how to fix it?

[image]

**///edit3:** I tried to fix around the query and it doesn't show the result that I wanted. This is the service that I am using for the repository

```
    @Autowired
    DataTransaksiDb dataTransaksiDb;

    @Override
    public List<String> getDenda(String tanggal, String nama, String masaPajak){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dataTransaksiDb.findAllDenda(tanggal, nama, masaPajak);
    }
```

and this is the controller where I am using the service. The controller is using a multipart file where the data is taken out from the CSV that is uploaded where within the CSV has the table that is the same as the database.

```
 @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public static void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (file.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.ms-excel")) {
            InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream());
            CSVParser csvParser = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(input);
            for (CSVRecord record : csvParser) {
                String nama = record.get("nama_wp");
                String masa = record.get("masa_pajak");
                String tanggal = record.get("tanggal");
                String denda = record.get("denda");
                String jumlahSetoran = record.get("jumlah_setoran");
                String pokok = record.get("pokok");
                String luasTanah = record.get("luas_tanah");
                String luasBangunan = record.get("luas_bangunan");

                try {
                    System.err.println(tanggal + "\n" + nama + "\n" + masa);
                    List<String> results = rekonsiliasiService.getDenda(tanggal, nama, masa);
                    System.err.println("results " + results);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }


            }


            response.sendRedirect("/rekonsiliasi");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("/rekonsiliasi");
        }
    }
```

Whatever the result of the input that I get, it keep getting catches by the nullpointerexception

**////EDIT4:**
I tried debugging it and from my controller, I tried to do `System.err.println(rekonsiliasiService.getDenda(tanggal,nama,masa));` and it keep me getting a NullPointerException. Then I tried to see if the problem is the input of the parameter itself within the service

```
@Override
    public List<String> getDenda(String tanggal, String nama, String masaPajak){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.err.println("tanggal " + tanggal + "\n" + "nama " + nama + "\n" + "masaPajak " + masaPajak);
        return dataTransaksiDb.findAllDenda(tanggal, nama, masaPajak);
    }
```

It never reached to the `System.err.println("tanggal " + tanggal + "\n" + "nama " + nama + "\n" + "masaPajak " + masaPajak);` within my Service layer.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@Query(value = "select d.denda from DataTransaksiModel d WHERE d.tanggal=:x AND d.namaWP = :y AND d.masaPajak=:z")
    List<String> findAllDenda(@Param("x")String x, @Param("y")String y,@Param("z") String z);
```

if it didn't work try this :

```
@Query(value = "select d.denda from data_transaksi_model d WHERE d.tanggal=:x AND d.nama_wp = :y AND d.masa_pajak=:z", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findAllDenda(@Param("x")String x, @Param("y")String y,@Param("z") String z);
```

Comment: It is still the same, I received java.lang.nullpointer.exception for it

Comment: you can try using your query but in the method try returning a list of strings and add @Param() also to attributes, 
@Query(value = "select d.denda from data_transaksi_model d WHERE d.tanggal=:x AND d.nama_wp = :y AND d.masa_pajak=:z", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findAllDenda(@Param("x")String x, @Param("y")String y,@Param("z") String z);
it should work. i dont know why you got null pointer, if it's not an sql exception or query exception. its not a query prb then.

Comment: Hmm... That's weird, I will add the part in my controller that use this query in my question

Comment: why catching null pointer exception ? try catching Exception instead to see the error !

Comment: The exception is `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I change catching to Exception

Comment: did you try the second solution i gave ?

Comment: i think you should debug this. try running the debugger and truck what is null. and try adding checkpoints in the service method call in the controller and in the service layer

Comment: I have tried to debug it and found a potential problem and I am lost on how to fix it. I have edited my question.

Comment: try adding a check point in the method signature and run the debugger, and when the debugger stops on the checkpoint he will give you the variables value, then check if they have value. I think one of them is null